# Merge PDFs landscape mode but don't rotate content PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to merge existing PDFs and put the paper in landscape mode but keep the content of the PDF not rotated. My code currently:

```
public static void mergePDFs(List<InputStream> streamOfPDFFiles, OutputStream outputStream, 
        boolean landscape) throws IOException {

    PDDocument mergedDocument = new PDDocument();
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
    for (InputStream streamOfPDFFile : streamOfPDFFiles) {
        PDDocument srcDoc = PDDocument.load(streamOfPDFFile);
        pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(mergedDocument, srcDoc);
        srcDoc.close();
    }

//        if (landscape) {
//            for (PDPage pdPage : mergedDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
//                pdPage.setRotation(90);
//            }
//        }

    mergedDocument.save(outputStream);
    mergedDocument.close();
}
```

setRotation doesn't work because if the input PDF file is already in landscape it will turn to portrait and it also rotates the content of the file. I just want to rotate the paper and let the content be as it was in the input file. Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried `setMediaBox()` on each page ?

Comment: ... and `setCropBox`... and considering the existing **Rotation** value when choosing the box coordinates...